# Generic template pointer in template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, pointers

I have a template class which has a pointer to the same class (but not necessarily using the same type). Here is an example:

```
template<class T>
class Foo{
    Foo(){}
    Foo* a;
    template<class U>
    void bar(Foo<U>* b){a=b;}
}
```

When I use it in my main function, everything seems to be working until I use a different template for the argument.

```
int main(){
    Foo<double> f1;
    Foo<double> f2;
    f1.bar(&f1);// no Errors

    Foo<bool> f3;
    Foo<double> f4;
    f3.bar(&f4);//Error : cannot convert 'Foo<double>*' to 'Foo<bool>*'
}
```

Is there anyway I can define a pointer in class `Foo` that has a "generic" pointer to the same class in it?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Are you asking for a pointer that can point to any kind of `Foo`? If so, consider making `Foo<T>` derive from an untemplated base class.

Comment: "the same class (but not necessarily ... the same type)" -- no, a **class** defines **one** type; you're talking about a **different instantiation of the same template**. Don't muddle templates and classes; they're two different things. A class template is a **pattern** for creating classes. It is not a class.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes, that's exactly what I meant. The solution that you proposed has solved the problem, but in that case, I can't use something that belongs to `Foo`. For example say we have a template function called `eval` :  `a->eval()` `FooBase has no member named eval`

Comment: Why not make `eval` virtual and add it to your `FooBase`？

Comment: @PeteBecker you're right : I want a pointer that points to any class with the pattern `Foo`

Comment: @xskxzr because `eval` returns a `T` which is the type that is used in the template.

Comment: @Elirovi There is no easy solution. The main constraint is that all types must be known at compile time. If what you are attempting worked, what would the return type of `a->eval()`? It would depend on what type `a` was, which would depend on what pointer you assigned to it, which can't necessarily be known at compile time.

Comment: This is impossible. Consider what you want to do. For different `T`, `a->eval()` has to have different types, so `a` must be a type dependent on `T`. On the other hand, for each `T`, `a` has to accept `Foo<U>*` for every `U`. Note conversion for pointers to class is valid only via derived-to-base conversion, so, again for each `T`, the type of `a` has to be a base of `Foo<U>` for every `U`. This means for each `U`, `Foo<U>` has infinite bases, which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway I can define a pointer in class Foo that has a "generic" pointer to the same class in it?

What you have is correct. What you are expecting to see is founded on probably a misunderstanding.

`Foo<bool>` and `Foo<double>` are totally different classes. Type/class templates allow you to use the compiler to generate new types but they themselves are not classes.

If you had to generate the classes manually, you would have:

```
class Foo_bool{
    Foo_bool(){}
    Foo_bool* a;

    ...
};

class Foo_double{
    Foo_double(){}
    Foo_double* a;

    ...
};
```

With that, it's easy to see why you can't use:

```
Foo_bool a;
Foo_double b;
a.a = &b;   // Not allowed
```

That is no different than using:

```
Foo<bool> a;
Foo<double> b;
a.a = &b;   // Not allowed
```

The closest you can come to achieving your goal is:

1. Create a base class for all instantiations of `Foo`.
2. Store a pointer to the base class.

Simple program that demonstrates the concept:

```
class FooBase
{
   public:
      virtual ~FooBase() {}
};

template<class T>
class Foo : public FooBase {
   public:
    Foo(){}
    template<class U>
    void bar(Foo<U>* b){a=b;}

   private:
    FooBase* a; // Note the change. This is not Foo* any longer.
};

int main()
{
   Foo<bool> a;
   Foo<double> b;
   a.bar(&b);
}
```

Comment: Ok, now I see. But I still don't have a solution.

Comment: @Elirovi, what's the justification for storing a pointer to a `Foo<double>` in a `Foo<bool>`?

Comment: The point here would be what OP really wants to do with the `a` data member in `Foo`.

Comment: @水飲み鳥, indeed. That's the core question the OP has to answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway I can define a pointer in class Foo that has a "generic" pointer to the same class in it?

That's what you already have:

```
    Foo* a;
```

What you actually want, I think, is a pointer to *any* instantiation of `Foo`. That's not possible. The question is: why do you *want* that? If you say exactly what you are trying to achieve, maybe you can get a more useful answer.

One possibility *might* be to use a base class:

```
class Base {
    // whatever common functionality you want in Foo goes here
};

template<class T>
class Foo : public Base {
    Foo(){}
    Base* a;
    template<class U>
    void bar(Foo<U>* b){a=b;}
}
```

Whether this will work for you is hard to say until you provide more information about what you are trying to achieve. I think we are hitting an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility besides the solutions with a common base class consists of defining the type of the `a` data member in `Foo` as `void *` instead of `Foo *`. That way any data pointer can be assigned to it (this one would be a *generic pointer*):

```
template<class T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(){}
    void* a;
    template<class U>
    void bar(Foo<U>* b){a=b;}

    ...
};
```

Then, you could define the following member template `convert_ptr()` to convert the pointer back to its original type:

```
template<class T>
class Foo {
    ...

    template<class U>
    Foo<U>* convert_ptr() {
        return reinterpret_cast<Foo<U>*>(a);
    }
};
```

As an example:

```
int main(){
    Foo<bool> f1;
    Foo<double> f2;

    f2.bar(&f1);
    Foo<bool> *p = f2.convert_ptr<bool>();
}
```

Bear in mind that not using the right template instance of `convert_ptr()` (e.g.: not casting `a` back to the pointer of the right type) will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an extra parameter to the template:

```
template<class T, class U=T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}
    Foo<U>* a;
    void bar(Foo<U>* b) { a = b; }
};

int main(){
    Foo<bool, double> f3;
    Foo<double> f4;
    f3.bar(&f4);

    return 0;
}
```

If the second template parameter is not specified, it will be equal to the first one. And this means that your pointer "a" will point to an object of the same type as "this".
If the second parameter is specified and it's different from the first one, your pointer "a" will point to a different type.

It's not a generic solution because you cannot change the second type once the object is created. But if you know from the start that

```
Foo<bool>
```

needs to point to

```
Foo<double>
```

it might work.